# error: class template placeholder not permitted in this context

Tags: c++, tuples, ctad

The following snippet compiles in gcc 12.1 but not in gcc 11.1. Unfortunately, I only have gcc 11 at hand as I'm crosscompiling for a microcontroller. Is there a way to make it work? Also what is this cryptic "use 'auto' for an abbreviated function template" all about?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:13,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:13,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:13,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:13,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+channel%0A%7B%0A++++int+a%3B%0A++++T+b%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Channels%3E%0Astruct+light%0A%7B%0A++++light(const+std::tuple%3CChannels...%3E%26+channels)%0A++++++++:+++channels_+%7B+channels+%7D%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++std::tuple%3CChannels...%3E+channels_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++light+li(std::tuple%7Bchannel(2,+2),+channel(2,false)%7D)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g111,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Os+-pthread%27,selection:(endColumn:45,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:45,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:45,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:45,startLineNumber:3),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct channel
{
    int a;
    T b;
};

template <typename... Channels>
struct light
{
    light(const std::tuple<Channels...>& channels)
        :   channels_ { channels }
    {
        
    }

    std::tuple<Channels...> channels_;
};

int main()
{
    light li(std::tuple{channel(2, 2), channel(2,false)});
}
```

Error (only in gcc 11.1):

```
<source>:25:14: error: class template placeholder 'std::tuple' not permitted in this context
   25 |     light li(std::tuple{channel(2, 2), channel(2,false)});
      |              ^~~
<source>:25:14: note: use 'auto' for an abbreviated function template
```

Interestingly, gcc 10.4 has something even different to say:

```
<source>:25:14: error: 'auto' parameter not permitted in this context
   25 |     light li(std::tuple{channel(2, 2), channel(2,false)});
      |              ^~~
```

I need a workaround that allows me to *not* specify all the template parameters of std::tuple as that would blow up my initializer to the point of unrecognizeability :/

Comment: That looks to me like a GCC bug at a glance, failing too fatally on trying a function declaration, but worst comes to worst, you could have an alias for the type on a separate line I guess. Might be able to find this in the bug tracker.

Comment: Did you enable C++17 using the `-std=c++17` compiler flag?

Comment: @NathanOliver I enabled C++20 even. You can test it using the given link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need a workaround ...

```
light li{ std::tuple{channel(2, 2), channel(2, false)} };
//      ^                                              ^
```

---

A slightly more involved workaround could be to add deduction guides and constraints.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template <class T>
struct channel {
    int a;
    T b;
};

// deduction guide for channel:
template<class T>
channel(int, T) -> channel<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;

// trait to check if a type is a channel
template<class> struct is_channel : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_channel<channel<T>> : std::true_type {};
template<class T> static inline bool is_channel_v = is_channel<T>::value;

// require channel based template parameters
template <class... Channels>
requires std::conjunction_v<is_channel<Channels>...>
struct light {
    template<class... Chs>
    light(Chs&&... channels) : channels_{std::forward<Chs>(channels)...} {}

    std::tuple<Channels...> channels_;
};

// deduction guide for light
template<class... Channels>
light(Channels...) -> light<std::remove_cvref_t<Channels>...>;
```

Now using `(`...`)` to initialize the `light` works even in gcc 11.1:

```cpp
int main() {
    channel x{ 2, std::string("Hello") };

    light li( channel(2, 2), channel(2, false), x);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/86jM8sYvb)

Comment: That works... I'm not even asking why

Comment: @glades Glad do hear it. I'm guessing some half-implemented C++20 version of uniform initialization in gcc. Not sure either.

Comment: If my guess is in the right direction, the braces stop the possibility of the line being a function declaration before the compiler gets tripped up by it.

Comment: @chris Could be, but it often reports that under `-Wvexing-parse` ... (even if not strictly vexing). Not sure ...